# Any good way to start 2 exes from VS 2008 IDE for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, client-server

I have an exe that is a 'server' and exe that is its client.

I would like that when I hit RUN (F5):

- server starts
- client starts with debugger attached

Any good ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Multiple projects in One solution and you want to start more than one then,

1. Right Click on Solution ->Properties ->Common Properties->StartupProject->Select Multiple Start Up Projects ->Set the Sequence.(suitable For WCF like Scenario When Server and Client should start together, but in same IDE instance for debugging)

Other Ways

- Right click on Project ->Debug->Select Start External Project-> Enter the Path.
- Go To tools menu And click on Attach To Process.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in the solution explorer, thene select debug->run new instance